# Is residual finiteness a property of "many" finitely presented groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Is there a reasonable random model for selecting a finitely presented group $G$ such that with positive probablity (or even with probability almost $1$) some of the following properties hold:

1. $G$ is residually finite.
2. $G$ is subgroup seperable (LERF).
3. The first $l_2$ Betti number of $G$ is positive.
4. The cost of $G$ is greater than 1.

Comment: Dear @StefanKohl I know that there exists a notion of generic finitely presented groups studied by (say) Arzhantseva and Olshanskii. They consider the proportion of finitely presented groups satisfying a certain property by fixing the number of generators and relations and go over all groups with these relations having length at most $M$. Then you take $M \to \infty$ and see what is the limiting probability. There probably exist other random models. I have heard that Gromov proved (or conjectured) that most groups are hyperbolic. In my question I ask if random groups are residually finite.

Comment: @StefanKohl for generic properties of groups see http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-11/S0002-9939-00-05508-8/ or http://www.researchgate.net/publication/232841778_Generic_properties_of_finitely_presented_groups_and_howson%27s_theorem so I want to know if residual finiteness is generic in this sense (or in a slightly different one). For results on one relator groups see Theorem 1.6 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.2829.pdf. For different definitions of a "random model" one can consult http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/randomgroups.pdf

Comment: I believe you are correct in saying that there are widely accepted definitions of random finitely presented groups, and significant results (by Gromov?) such as almost all finitely presented groups are hyperbolic. But I have never encountered a definition of a random finitely generated group, so perhaps you should frame your question for finitely presented groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am ready to restrict my attention to finitely presented groups (edited the question).

Comment: Since your edit (i.e. restriction to finitely *presented* groups) made your question clear, I removed my initial comment.

Comment: @Derek: I'm skeptical about your meaning of "widely accepted". That Gromov's model of random groups is interesting and useful is certainly widely accepted; it does not mean that it's the right definition of random finitely presented groups; it seems quite clear that there is none. (Moreover it's a random presentation rather than a random group...). Furthermore in density $>1/2$ Gromov's random groups are the trivial group and I wouldn't infer that finitely presented groups are almost surely trivial :)

Comment: @Derek: about f.g. groups rather than f.p.: there is a space of marked f.g. groups on $k$ generators which is a nice compact space. In this space there are topological notions of large subsets, e.g. $G_\delta$ subsets, or the intersection of $G_\delta$ subsets with subsets of countable complement. Perhaps there are natural classes of measure but I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A random group at density less than 1/6 is known to be the fundamental group of a compact, non-positively curved cube complex, by Ollivier--Wise.  By Agol's theorem, all such hyperbolic groups are virtually special, and hence residually finite, QCERF, etc.

Comment: but is it also LERF? This was my second question.

Comment: Pablo, LERF isn't really the right notion here. One can ask whether every fg subgroup is qc. This is known to fail for random 2-generator 1-relator groups, and presumably it fails in general.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. And one last thing on this issue, what about my third question? Do random groups at density $< 1/6$ have positive first $l_2$ Betti number? In fact I am really interested in the positivity of the rank gradient.

Comment: Pablo, I think this is an interesting question.  The result I mentioned about 2-generator 1-relator groups is in a paper of Dunfield and (Dylan) Thurston. They prove that a random 2-generator 1-relator group is fg-free-by-cyclic with probability strictly between 0 and 1.  In particular, at least some of the time, such groups have zero rank gradient.  As far as I know, nothing is known about models with more generators or relations.

Comment: (But you might like to check out the work of Sapir and his co-authors on random 1-relator groups with more generators.)

Comment: So maybe the right thing to ask about is the positivity of the rank gradient of the fundamental group of a compact, non-positively curved cube complex, or virtually special hyperbolic groups. Is something known about these groups?

Comment: Pablo, this is also a good question. Do you want to send me an e-mail?

Comment: Will definitely be done.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Henry Wilton](http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/wises-conjecture/) (who will probably comment extensively himself), the question of whether a random finitely presented group is residually finite was wide open in 2012 (and I am pretty sure not enough has changed now, outside of 3-manifold group context).

Comment: Yes it has changed a lot, because several random models (e.g. Gromov's model at low density) provides almost surely $C'(1/6)$ f.p. groups, which are residually finite by Agol's result (combined with the Haglund-Wise theory). This goes far beyond 3-manifold groups.

Comment: @YCor Yves knows a lot more, so maybe he should post an answer :)

Comment: @YCor is there a chance that in this model we also have subgroup separability (LERF) almost surely? or with positive probability?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that my blog post appeared the week before Agol's preprint proving the virtual Haken conjecture (as explained in the subsequent blog post).  As Yves says, this changed everything.