# A hyperbolic group with a small profinite completion

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups

Is there a finitely generated non-elementary word hyperbolic group the profinite completion of which is known (or conjectured) to be rather restricted, that is: abelian, pro-$p$, virtually prosolvable, etc. ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a famous open question whether every word-hyperbolic group is residually finite.  Kapovich--Wise showed that this is equivalent to asking whether every non-trivial word-hyperbolic group has non-trivial profinite completion.  In the other direction, Agol--Groves--Manning showed that it's equivalent to asking whether every quasiconvex subgroup of every word-hyperbolic group is separable.

In particular, since non-elementary word-hyperbolic groups always contain quasiconvex non-abelian free subgroups, if an example were known with virtually prosolvable profinite completion, the above questions would all be answered in the negative.

The best conjectural candidates for non-elementary word-hyperbolic groups with restricted profinite completion (in some sense) are cocompact lattices in $Sp(n,1)$ (aka quaternionic hyperbolic lattices).  It's unknown whether these have the congruence subgroup property, and if they do, then I believe it again follows that all the above questions are answered in the negative.

Comment: In light of this, it seems plausible that, in a certain statistical sense (random group model), subgroup separability will be a property of almost all finitely presented groups (since these are almost always hyperbolic). I suspect that this is the case for Gromov's model with low density (say d < 1/5). I have already asked this in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191965/is-residual-finiteness-a-property-of-many-finitely-presented-groups . Do you know of someone who can help with this?

Comment: @Pablo, I answered your question.  It's still very unclear what happens to random groups at higher densities, which can't possibly be virtually special.